# Como configurar o IncrementBy de um campo Id do PostGre usando o Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Tenho uma tabela mapeada para o PostGre, mas quando dou update no banco, o Campo PessoaFisicaEnderecoTipoId está sendo autoincrementado de 10 em 10 (por padrão). Como faço para mapear de forma que o IncrementBy seja setado para autoincrementar de 1 em 1?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mapeamento da tabela:

```
public class PessoaFisicaEnderecoTipoMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PessoaFisicaEnderecoTipo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PessoaFisicaEnderecoTipo> builder)
    {

        builder.ToTable("PessoaFisicaEnderecoTipo");

        builder.HasKey(pfet => pfet.Id);

        builder.Property(pfet => pfet.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PessoaFisicaEnderecoTipoId")
            .ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(pfet => pfet.Descricao)
           .HasColumnName("Descricao")
           .HasColumnType("character varying(50)")
           .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(pfet => pfet.PadraoSistema)
          .HasColumnName("PadraoSistema")
          .HasColumnType("boolean");

    }


}
```

Comment: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html e uma explicação aqui: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/336 leia e depois você me fala!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequência de 10 em 10 é o default quando você esta utilizando `ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo`. Você pode criar sua sequência personalizada de 1 em 1 e informar como abaixo:

```
modelBuilder.HasSequence("minha_sequencia", b => b.IncrementsBy(1))    

builder.Property(pfet => pfet.Id)
    .HasColumnName("PessoaFisicaEnderecoTipoId")
    .ForNpgsqlUseSequenceHiLo("minha_sequencia")
    .IsRequired();
```

Comment: Obrigado @Fabri Damazio. Funcionou 100!